# Cypress: can't download file after clicking on button

Tags: javascript, file, testing, cypress

I'm using Cypress to emulate some human behavior. I need to click on a button which will start a file download. I need to wait for the file to download, and then be able to read the file content. I can't access the Download URL, I need to really emulate the click.

Doing this doesn't work:

```
cy.get('[class="myclass"]').contains('Download').click();
cy.wait(60000);
```

EDIT:

I'm not getting any particular error. The test just finishes OK. It is just that, I'm expecting the file to be downloaded in the same directory of the test. Of course, my expectations may be totally wrong as it is very clear I'm missing something.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the error that you sre getting ?

Comment: See my last edition. Thanks.

Comment: Check this plugin, as Cypress does not support downloading files out of the box: https://github.com/Xvier/cypress-downloadfile

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out but at first glance it won't work for my purposes, since I need to click on a button.